# Remove-Item does not delete folder

Tags: powershell, shell, terminal, command, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to delete a folder, but I get error `can't remove because directory is not empty`

I used this command :

```
Remove-Item \\wsl.localhost\Debian\home\my_folder_to_delete -Recurse -Force
```

How can I force this delete ?

PS: I use powerShell on windows 11

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141528/cannot-remove-item-the-directory-is-not-empty

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried this, and still get the same error

Comment: Does this work? `Get-Item \\wsl.localhost\Debian\home\my_folder_to_delete | % Delete($true)`

Comment: Nope, I still see "directory is not empty" :( thx for your help

Comment: Even if you have your powershell running as administrator?

Comment: Yes. I think this is due to the fact that the folder is in a wsl environment (linux/Debian) and my powershell in Widows's shell

Comment: my guess you might need to approach this from your linux shell using `rm -rf` but hopefully someone else can help

Comment: Do you know how can I use the linux shell ? I'm a beginner in this kind of things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51861309/11810933), it's likely that the directory (or some file within it) is still being accessed by WSL.

**Important**: For all answers below, please make sure that the directory does not include any critical files or symlinks to critical directories, as you'll be recursively removing everything in there.

##### Option 1: Getting Windows PowerShell to do it

*Not recommended, but simply to demonstrate the problem and how to resolve it.  For the proper way to do this, see Option 2.*

- Exit any WSL shell that you may have running
- From PowerShell:

  ```
  wsl --shutdown
  ```

That should release in "in-use" files.

- Try the `Remove-Item` command again.

##### Option 2:  The Linux way

From the comments suggesting doing this from the Linux shell:

> Do you know how can I use the Linux shell? I'm a beginner in this kind of things

Well, there's nothing wrong with being a beginner (we *all* were at one point), but keep in mind that WSL *is* Linux in most ways.  Understanding some "Linux basics" will be pretty necessary to finding your way around WSL.  *Side-note -- I'm considering doing a YouTube series on learning Linux with WSL.  Keep an eye on my [Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11810933/notthedr01ds) if interested, and let me know in a comment if this would be interesting to you.*

> `\\wsl.localhost\Debian\home\my_folder_to_delete`

That translates to `/home/my_folder_to_delete` inside Debian.  With that in mind, it's an odd directory to have created or want to delete.  Just make sure you aren't removing your home directory, as that will cause issues.

But to remove it (most safely):

```
cd /home
[ ! -L my_folder_to_delete] && rm -rf --one-file-system my_folder_to_delete
```

Normally, in Linux, a simply `rm -rf my_folder_to_delete` would be sufficient, but this is a bit of my paranoid, over-protective version of the command to avoid something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1354555/1165986) from happening.

Note that if you created the directory as `sudo` or `root`, you may have to use the following:

```
cd /home
[ ! -L my_folder_to_delete] && sudo rm -rf --one-file-system my_folder_to_delete
```

##### Option 3:  The Linux + PowerShell way

It's possible to use the *Linux* version of PowerShell inside Debian.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/install-debian?view=powershell-7.3) for installation instructions.  You can even set your user shell to PowerShell using the `chsh` command.

I honestly can't decide whether this is a good or bad idea for a Linux newbie, though.